# Generate Table dynamically display error Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm creating a table that uses data from a json, the json "policies" change when I click on different links in the page, the thing is that when I click and the state change, I have to generate the table again with the new json, but I get an

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: processUpdates(): Unable to find child 1 of element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a `<tbody>` when using tables, nesting tags like `<form>`, `<p>`, or `<a>`, or using non-SVG elements in an `<svg>` parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID `.0.1.0.2.3.1.1.2.0.1`.

The first time the page loads the table is correctly generated.

```
module.exports = React.createClass({

onPoliciesChange: function (policiesStore) {
    this.setState(policiesStore);
},

getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        policies: []
    };
},

componentDidMount: function () {
    this.unsubscribeAlertsStore = AlertsStore.listen(this.onPoliciesChange);
},

componentWillUnmount: function () {
    this.unsubscribeAlertsStore();
},


cols: [
    { key: 'name', label: 'Name'},
    { key: 'severity', label: 'Severity' },
    { key: 'width', label: 'Width' },
    { key: 'pulsate', label: 'Pulsate' }        
],

generateHeaders: function () {
    var cols = this.cols;  // [{key, label}]

    // generate our header (th) cell components
    return cols.map(function (colData) {
        return <th key={colData.key}> {colData.label} </th>;
    });
},

generateRows: function () {
    var slf = this;
    var cols = this.cols,  // [{key, label}]
        data = this.data;
    //per each item 
    return this.state.policies.map(function (item) {
        // handle the column data within each row
        var cells = cols.map(function (colData) {
            return <td> {item[colData.key]} </td>;          
        });
        return <tr key={item.id}> {cells} </tr>;
    });
},

render: function () {

    var headerComponents = this.generateHeaders(),
        rowComponents = this.generateRows();
    return (
        <table className="table table-condensed table-striped">
            <thead> {headerComponents} </thead>
                <tbody> {rowComponents} </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just move the  from the render to the function that creates the rows:

```
generateRows: function () {
        var severity = this.renderSeverity();
        var slf = this;
        var cols = this.cols,  // [{key, label}]
            data = this.data;
        //per each item 
        return this.state.policies.map(function (item) {
            // handle the column data within each row
            var cells = cols.map(function (colData) {
                if (colData.key === 'width') {
                    //return <td> <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" onChange={slf.onChange.bind(null, id) }/></td>;
                    return <td> <input type="checkbox"  onChange={slf.onChangeWidth.bind(null, item.id) }/></td>;
                } else if (colData.key === 'pulsate') {
                    return <td> <input type="checkbox"  onChange={slf.onChangePulsate.bind(null, item.id) }/></td>;

                } if (colData.key === 'policyCheck') {
                    return <td> <input type="checkbox"  onChange={slf.onChangePolicy.bind(null, item.id) }/></td>;
                } else if (colData.key === 'severity') {
                    // colData.key might be "firstName"

                    return <td>{item[colData.key]} {slf.renderSeverity(item.severity) }</td>;
                } else {
                    // colData.key might be "firstName"
                    return <td> {item[colData.key]} </td>;
                }
            });
            return <tbody><tr key={item.id}> {cells} </tr></tbody>;
        });
    }
```